# How to do arithmetic modulo another number, without overflow?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow, integer-arithmetic, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to implement a fast primality test for Rust's `u32` and `u64` datatypes. As part of it, I need to compute `(n*n)%d` where `n` and `d` are `u32` (or `u64`, respectively).

While the result can easily fit in the datatype, I'm at a loss for how to compute this. As far as I know there is no processor primitive for this.

For `u32` we can fake it -- cast up to `u64`, so that the product won't overflow, then take the modulus, then cast back down to `u32`, knowing this won't overflow. However since I don't have a `u128` datatype (as far as I know) this trick won't work for `u64`.

So for `u64`, the most obvious way I can think of to accomplish this is to somehow compute `x*y` to get a pair `(carry, product)` of `u64`, so we capture the amount of overflow instead of just losing it (or panicking, or whatever).

Is there a way to do this? Or another standard way to solve the problem?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/u128/

Comment: Just use this: http://huonw.github.io/primal/primal/fn.is_prime.html

Comment: [Wiki modular arithmetic example implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Example_implementations)

Comment: @red75prime if you (or someone) can turn that into an answer I would love to accept it.

Comment: @red75prime Why do not you post it as answer?

Comment: @Boiethios that's a good trick if you're on nightly, but then I have to wonder how to do it for `u128` (and so on until I run out of higher-bit datatypes)

Comment: @RichardRast Sure, I just wanted to answer your interrogation about `u128`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Richard Rast [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918104/how-to-do-arithmetic-modulo-another-number-without-overflow#comment78806816_45923436) that Wikipedia version works only with 63-bit integers. I extended the code provided by Boiethios to work with full range of 64-bit unsigned integers.

```
fn mul_mod64(mut x: u64, mut y: u64, m: u64) -> u64 {
    let msb = 0x8000_0000_0000_0000;
    let mut d = 0;
    let mp2 = m >> 1;
    x %= m;
    y %= m;

    if m & msb == 0 {
        for _ in 0..64 {
            d = if d > mp2 {
                (d << 1) - m
            } else {
                d << 1
            };
            if x & msb != 0 {
                d += y;
            }
            if d >= m {
                d -= m;
            }
            x <<= 1;
        }
        d
    } else {
        for _ in 0..64 {
            d = if d > mp2 {
                d.wrapping_shl(1).wrapping_sub(m)
            } else {
                // the case d == m && x == 0 is taken care of 
                // after the end of the loop
                d << 1
            };
            if x & msb != 0 {
                let (mut d1, overflow) = d.overflowing_add(y);
                if overflow {
                    d1 = d1.wrapping_sub(m);
                }
                d = if d1 >= m { d1 - m } else { d1 };
            }
            x <<= 1;
        }
        if d >= m { d - m } else { d }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_mul_mod64() {
    let half = 1 << 16;
    let max = std::u64::MAX;

    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(0, 0, 2), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1, 0, 2), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(0, 1, 2), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1, 1, 2), 1);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(42, 1, 2), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1, 42, 2), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(42, 42, 2), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(42, 42, 42), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(42, 42, 41), 1);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1239876, 2948635, 234897), 163320);

    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1239876, 2948635, half), 18476);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(half, half, half), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(half+1, half+1, half), 1);

    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(max, max, max), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1239876, 2948635, max), 3655941769260);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1239876, max, max), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(1239876, max-1, max), max-1239876);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(max, 2948635, max), 0);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(max-1, 2948635, max), max-2948635);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(max-1, max-1, max), 1);
    assert_eq!(mul_mod64(2, max/2, max-1), 0);
}
```

Comment: @mcarton what is `half` half of?

Comment: @Shepmaster now that I think about it, nothing :)

Comment: I regret to say that I have not gone through the work of understanding this code :( but I have tested it thoroughly and it works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative approach (there's now a `u128` datatype):

```
fn mul_mod(a: u64, b: u64, m: u64) -> u64 {
    let (a, b, m) = (a as u128, b as u128, m as u128);
    ((a * b) % m) as u64
}
```

This approach just leans on LLVM's 128 bit integer arithmetic.

The thing I like about this version is that it's really easy to convince yourself that the solution is correct for the entire domain. Since `a` and `b` are `u64`s the product is guaranteed to fit in a `u128`, and since `m` is a `u64` the downcast at the end is guaranteed to be safe.

I don't know how performance compares to other approaches, but I would be pretty surprised if it were dramatically slower. If you really care about performance you're going to want to run some benchmarks and try a few alternatives in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple mathematics:

```
(n*n)%d = (n%d)*(n%d)%d
```

To see that this is indeed true, set `n = k*d+r`:

```
n*n%d = k**2*d**2+2*k*d*r+r**2 %d = r**2%d = (n%d)*(n%d)%d
```

Comment: strictly speaking `n * n % d = (n % d) * (n % d) % d`

Comment: This can still overflow if `d` is large.

Comment: @interjay Specifically, it can overflow if `d > 2^16`

Answer (score 1):

[red75prime added a useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918104/how-to-do-arithmetic-modulo-another-number-without-overflow#comment78795079_45918104). Here is the Rust code to calculate a modulo of two multiplied numbers, taken from Wikipedia:

```
fn mul_mod(mut x: u64, mut y: u64, m: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut d = 0_u64;
    let mp2 = m >> 1;
    x %= m;
    y %= m;

    for _ in 0..64 {
        d = if d > mp2 {
            (d << 1) - m
        } else {
            d << 1
        };
        if x & 0x8000_0000_0000_0000_u64 != 0 {
            d += y;
        }
        if d > m {
            d -= m;
        }
        x <<= 1;
    }
    d
}
```

Comment: @red75prime If you want to post your own answer, I delete mine.

Comment: No, it's fine. The problem is this algorithm isn't correct. I found one bug `if d > m ...` should be `if d >= m ...`. Another one causes subtract with overflow in ` (d << 1) - m`. I didn't find why yet.

Comment: Also it seems to give incorrect answers. 11552001120680995*15777587326414455 (mod 18442563521290148565) should be 844062957336182220, algorithm gives 13054753449364403936

Comment: Note that the wikipedia section indicates that all arguments (`x`, `y` and `m`) must be at most 63 bits (that is, $<2^63$). @red75prime your given arguments (here, the modulus) uses all 64 bits.